# To lock and unlock device using robotium

Tags: robotium, keyguardlock

I'm writing robotium tescases for lockscreen. in order to test it i need to 'Lock' and 'Unlock' device (Clicking on device hardware button).

I tried with KEYCODE_POWER, searched for other alternatives,but of no use.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Any luck? I'm trying to do the same

Comment: Is this topic solved?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `drag()`? That may unlock it, but I'm not sure how to lock. It may depend on the device itself.

Comment: to hit back button we have a method called solo.goback(). likewise do we have any method to call on lock device and make it to wake up(not unlocking device) so that we can get lockscreen to test on.